# How do you change alternating background row colors of a gtk.TreeView in pygtk?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I'm trying to change the alternating background color of a treeview. I know that this should normally be left up to the theme, but I'd like to override to test the gtk Style functionality.  According to the treeview documentation [here](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeview.html), I learned that the TreeView has several style options that are Read-only, including "even-row-color", "odd-row-color" and "allow-rules"(which according to the documentation, allows drawing of even and odd row colors).  And I know that in order to override those Read-only settings I've got to change the style in a gtkrc-style file or string.

So my string for a treeview looks like:

```
    gtk.rc_parse_string( """
        style "custom-treestyle"{
            GtkTreeView::odd-row-color = "#00CBFF"
            GtkTreeView::even-row-color = "#90EE90"
            GtkTreeView::allow-rules = 1
        }
        widget "*custom_treeview*" style "custom-treestyle"
    """)
    treeview.set_name("custom_treeview" )
```

This parses without error and the result is that the even-row-color gets applied to both even and odd rows.

EDIT: I discovered from some more testing that my parse string must be getting overridden from some other style settings.

```
print treeview.style_get_property( 'allow-rules' )
print treeview.style_get_property( 'odd-row-color')
print treeview.style_get_property( 'even-row-color')
```

Gives the result:

```
True
None
None
```

Which are all default settings.  Normally I would think that it's simply not parsing the string and setting the appropriate values, but in this case the background color **does** change to the color I specified( only it paints every row's background to one color).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out my issue with this styling method.
The 'allow-rules' style property isn't the only property that tells the treeview to color the rows in alternating colors. According to the documentation, the treeview has *another* property that hints to the engine that it should draw rows in alternating colors. The 'rules-hint' property, False by default, when True successfully colors my TreeView in alternating odd/even row colors!

So, in code, add this line to the code in the question:

```
treeview.set_rules_hint( True )
```

And that's it, a TreeView with alternating colored rows!